# Google Sheets App-Script bug? setValues() not working correctly in merged cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet with an array of data defined in the app-script and and two setValues() statements to write out that same data.

The first block to be written out contains 3 rows of horizontally merged cells. Each cell is merged with 24 columns as that is what my project requires.

The second block is the same but the cells are not merged.

The data supplied is sufficient to occupy 3 rows of 5 cells.

Upon executing the function, the first setValues() statement only writes the first column in the block, instead of doing so for all 5 merged columns.

The second setValues() statement works correctly, setting all values in each of first five cells for each of the three rows.

See a demo sheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GveFAcsAUMa3JuaFR2YQdmn9KHZ_PZhZQDP-F7sCOhQ/edit?usp=sharing).

See Screenshot:
[image]

Here is the code:

```
function testMergedWriteOut() {

  var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet     = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var data      = new Array ( [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]], [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]], [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]] );

  Logger.log( data );

  // Write out the results in an merged range.
  sheet.getRange( 1, 2, 3, 5 ).setValues( data ); // row, col, numrow, numcol

  // Write out the results in an unmerged range.
  sheet.getRange( 5, 2, 3, 5 ).setValues( data );

}
```

Here is the console output:

> 11:30:15 AM    Notice  Execution started
> 11:30:20 AM Info    [[[1.0], [2.0], [3.0], [4.0], [5.0]], [[1.0], [2.0], [3.0], [4.0], [5.0]], [[1.0], [2.0], [3.0], [4.0], [5.0]]]
> 11:30:17 AM Notice  Execution completed

Comment: A [mre] could help here. There are probably a lot of details in the question which are not relevant to the issue - or could be shown with a much simpler example (one that we could recreate for ourselves).

Comment: One thing that I don't understand: How is `totalHrs` populated, and why does its data appear to be a three-dimensional array `[ [ [0.0] ], [ [0.0] ], [ [48.0] ] ]` (not a 2-D array)?

Comment: You have not provide a reproducible example so I'm not going to read any further.

Comment: @andrewjames Thanks for your suggestions. I have provided the requested example and removed any unnecessary details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Issue:

The different cells in a merged range are actually considered different cells when working with [Ranges](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range). That means that the `5` in `sheet.getRange( 1, 2, 3, 5 )` refers to columns `B` to `F`, not to the five groups of merged columns.

Also, in order to populate a merged range, you have to write to the top-left cell in the range (for example, it would be `B1` for the first range in your case). Trying to populate other cells in the merged range (e.g. `C1`) won't produce any result.

#### Solution:

Populate the different merged ranges iteratively.

For example, replace this:

```
sheet.getRange( 1, 2, 3, 5 ).setValues(data);
```

With this:

```
var mergedRangeColumns = 24;
for (let i = 0; i < data[0].length; i++) {
  var columnSet = data.map(row => row[i]);
  sheet.getRange(1, 2 + i * mergedRangeColumns, 3).setValues(columnSet);
}
```

Comment: Gracias Señor. Works perfectly.